# Using hitTest instead of mouseOver / mouseOut

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Almost all of the Flex components have mouseOver/mouseOut or rollOver/rollOut events. Requires that these events called not the mouse cursor, but on the other element, such as Image or Bitmap.

For example, there is a Colomn Chart and image animations above it and I need to get the data (colomn value or index) when the image is over the column. If it were a component, then I would use hitTest. But what to do if it is chart?

Comment: An image over a column? huh? You should review the events.http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/charts/ColumnChart.html#eventSummary

Comment: I know that required event is not. I need to the image react to the chart component as well as in the mouse.

Comment: sorry I just do not understand what you are saying with about an image

Answer (score 0):

Can't you tell the image/bitmap to not be mouseEnabled?

Comment: What do you mean mouseEnabled? The image moves independently from the movement of the mouse.

Comment: Okay, but you could say `imageSprite.mouseEnabled = false` to prevent the image sprite to be mouse sensitive at all.

Answer (score 0):

i can't understand your question properly, eventhough i m trying this...

if you add mouselisteners on the chart and whenever the event is dispatch check..

```
position.x = event.currentTarget.mouseX;
position.y = event.currentTarget.mouseY;
```

then you can try with hitTest.

or

```
if(obj.hitTestPoint(position.x,position.y)){

}
```

this might be work....